# Windows 7 folder icons cache doesnt refresh when icon changed?

Tags: windows-7, icons

I updated my .exe icon, but the new icon doesn't show up in the folder. Only way to make it work is to create new folder and copy the .exe file there.

How do I tell Windows 7 to refresh the cached icons?

Answer (score 3):

You will need to delete your Icon Cache and reboot.

Instructions can be found here: http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/49819-icon-cache-rebuild.html

Comment: You can also just restart Explorer, rather than a full reboot.

Comment: you can, but that creates other issues

Answer (score 1):

1) Save your work before running this cmd

2) Right-click on **START** and choose **CMD (As Admin)**

3) Run this code:

```
set iconcache=%localappdata%\IconCache.db && ie4uinit.exe -ClearIconCache && taskkill /IM explorer.exe /F && del "%iconcache%" /A && del "%localappdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer\iconcache*" /A &&  taskkill.exe /f /im explorer.exe && explorer
```

Comment: And also need to run `explorer` in CMD to bring back Windows Explorer and probably your desktop